# service manager error when trying to run python with selenium chromedriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, python-3.6

I am getting this error:

```
[7144:13212:1028/134009.633:ERROR:service_manager.cc(156)] Connection InterfaceProviderSpec prevented service: content_plugin from binding interface: memory_instrumentation::mojom::Coordinator exposed by: content_browser
```

Now I think that is it related that the url i am trying to open not in english.

My script:

```
    from selenium import webdriver  
browser = webdriver.Chrome()  
browser.get(URL)  

browser.quit()
```

selenium version: `3.6.0`
chromedriver version `2.33`
chrome version `61`
using python `3.6`

Comment: I doubt that's the reason... open a URL that *is* in English to test that then. My guess is it's some configuration problem, mismatched version numbers, etc. Are you sure you don't have some rogue addin that's causing issues?